# how to insert both drop down values and text field values in to cart

Tags: jsp

There is form text field when user select one of the options such as  windows or linux the text field of cpu and memory changes to drop down,then user selects any one option and tries to add it cart but it is giving error message.Even though the values are inserted its not getting in to cart but when user clicks on the solaries in the form then cpu and memory will text field when user insert the value and clicks on add to cart it is working fine it should work even for drop down also.
please help me solve this issue

My entire code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
<script src="lib/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


    <br>
</header>
<div align="center">
    <form action = "GetEstimation" method = "post">
    <p id="message"></p>
    <table id="formTable">
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td> <label>Environment </label> </td>
            <td> <label>form </label> </td>
            <td> <label>Type </label> </td>

            <td><label id="myLabel" >Model</label> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  <select  name ="Environment"id="Environment" required>
                  <option value ="" selected Disabled>Select Environment</option>
                  <option>abc</option>
                <option>bcd</option>
                <option>efg</option>
                  </select> </td>

            <td>  <select name="form" id="form"  
            onchange ="check(this)" required>
                  <option value ="" selected Disabled>Select Platform</option>
                <option>windows</option>
                <option>linux</option>
                <option>solaries</option>

                  </select> </td>     
            <td>  <select name="Type" id="Type"required>
                  <option value ="" selected Disabled>Select Server Type</option>
                  <option>ABC</option>
                  <option>DEF</option>
                  <option>QAZ</option>
                  <option>ASF</option>
                  <option>NS</option>
                  </select> </td>         




      <td> <select name = "Model" id="Model"required>
        <option value="" selected Disabled>Select Hardware</option>
        <option>abc</option>
        <option>bcd</option>
        <option>efg</option>
        </select> </td>        

        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td> <label>Cpu</label> </td>
            <td> <label>Memory</label> </td>
            <td> <label>Storage</label> </td>
            <td> <label>Servers</label> </td>       
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <input type ="text" name ="Cpu" id="Cpu"required> 
            <select id = "mass" style="display:none;"></select></td>
            <td> <input type ="text" name ="Memory" id="Memory"required> 
            <select id = "platforms" style="display:none;"></select></td>
            <td> <input type ="text" name ="Storage" id="Storage"required> </td>
            <td> <input type ="text" name ="Servers" id="Servers"required> </td>
            <td> <input type ="button" class="cartBtn" onclick="addTo()" value="Add to Cart"/>

        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


  <table  id="cartTable">

        <tr>
            <th><label>Environment</label></th>
            <th><label>form</label></th>
            <th><label>Type</label></th>
            <th><label>Model</label></th>
              <th><label>Cpu</label></th>
              <th><label>Memory</label></th>
              <th><label>Storage</label></th>
              <th><label>Servers</label></th>
        </tr>

    <tr id = "show" style="display:none;">
    <td> <input type ="text"  readonly ></td>
    <td> <input type ="text"  readonly></td>
    <td> <input type ="text"  readonly></td>
    <td> <input type ="text"  readonly></td>
    <td> <input type ="text"  readonly></td>
    <td> <input type ="text"  readonly></td>
    <td> <input type ="text"  readonly></td>
    <td> <input type ="text"  readonly></td>

    <td><input type="button" class="cartBtn" value="Remove" onclick="remove(this)" /></td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
function addTo() 
  { // to add rows and copy value to cart
  if((document.getElementById("Environment").value === "") || (document.getElementById("form").value === "") || (document.getElementById("Type").value === "") || (document.getElementById("Cpu").value === "")||
    (document.getElementById("Memory").value === "")||
    (document.getElementById("Storage").value === "")||
    (document.getElementById("Servers").value === "")) {
    //display error message
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "All fields required";


  } else {
    //unhiding  1st row to cloned it
    document.getElementById('show').style.display = "";
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "";
    var table = document.getElementById('cartTable');

    var new_row = table.rows[1].cloneNode(true); // clones the first row 
    var len = table.rows.length; // number of rows in table
    var inp1 = new_row.cells[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp1.value = document.getElementById("Environment").value;
    var inp2 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp2.value = document.getElementById("form").value;
    var inp3 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp3.value = document.getElementById("Type").value;
    var inp4 = new_row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp4.value = document.getElementById("Model").value;
     var inp5 = new_row.cells[4].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp5.value = document.getElementById("Cpu").value;
     var inp6 = new_row.cells[5].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp6.value = document.getElementById("Memory").value;
     var inp7 = new_row.cells[6].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp7.value = document.getElementById("Storage").value;

     var inp8 = new_row.cells[7].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp8.value = document.getElementById("Servers").value;
    table.appendChild(new_row);
    //hide again after cloning 
    document.getElementById('show').style.display = 'none';
  }
}


function check(s)
{
    document.getElementById('Memory').value ='';
    document.getElementById('Cpu').value ='';
    document.getElementById('platforms').innerHTML='<option>Select Core</option><option>1</option><option>2</option>';
    document.getElementById('mass').innerHTML='<option>Select memory</option><option>2</option><option>4</option>';


   var c= s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
   //Here You Can Start Loading your states with each country
   if(c !="windows" && c !="linux")
   {
    document.getElementById('Memory').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('Cpu').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('platforms').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('mass').style.display='none';
   }
  else
   {
    document.getElementById('Memory').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('Cpu').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('platforms').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('mass').style.display='block';
   }
}
```

Comment: i provided my code in this link  https://plnkr.co/edit/qjswaRpKKPoRDmKM

Comment: Just update the code in SO .

Comment: should i need to write  code here???

Comment: I have updated what is your issue now ?? I cant quietly understand your problem

Comment: when i select linux in my form my text filed of cpu and memory changes to dropdown i select the option and when i try to add to cart it is giving msg as fill all required details

Comment: i need the values of that dropdowns to get inserted to cart

Comment: it is working fine for text filed i need same thing to dropdown also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to check if the select-box are display or not depending on that do further process.If select-box are display you don't need to check the text-box with `id="Cpu"` and `id="Memory"` because they don't display else check all.

**Demo Code** :

```js
function addTo() { // to add rows and copy value to cart
  //checking if the slect box are display if yes
  if ((document.getElementById('platforms').style.display == "block") || (document.getElementById('mass').style.display == "block")) {
    //checking other fields if null ( leaving Cpu & memory)
    if ((document.getElementById("Environment").value === "") || (document.getElementById("form").value === "") || (document.getElementById("Type").value === "") ||
      (document.getElementById("Storage").value === "") ||
      (document.getElementById("Servers").value === "")) {
      //display error message
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "All fields required";

    } else {

      //unhiding  1st row to cloned it
      document.getElementById('show').style.display = "";
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "";
      var table = document.getElementById('cartTable');

      var new_row = table.rows[1].cloneNode(true); // clones the first row 
      var len = table.rows.length; // number of rows in table
      var inp1 = new_row.cells[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
      inp1.value = document.getElementById("Environment").value;
      var inp2 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
      inp2.value = document.getElementById("form").value;
      var inp3 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
      inp3.value = document.getElementById("Type").value;
      var inp4 = new_row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

      inp4.value = document.getElementById("Model").value;

      var inp5 = new_row.cells[4].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

      inp5.value = document.getElementById("mass").value;

      var inp6 = new_row.cells[5].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

      inp6.value = document.getElementById("platforms").value;

      var inp7 = new_row.cells[6].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
      inp7.value = document.getElementById("Storage").value;

      var inp8 = new_row.cells[7].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
      inp8.value = document.getElementById("Servers").value;
      table.appendChild(new_row);
      //hide again after cloning 
      document.getElementById('show').style.display = 'none';

    }
  } else {
    if ((document.getElementById("Environment").value === "") || (document.getElementById("form").value === "") || (document.getElementById("Type").value === "") || (document.getElementById("Cpu").value === "") ||
      (document.getElementById("Memory").value === "") ||
      (document.getElementById("Storage").value === "") ||
      (document.getElementById("Servers").value === "")) {

      //display error message
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "All fields required";


    } else {

      //unhiding  1st row to cloned it
      document.getElementById('show').style.display = "";
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "";
      var table = document.getElementById('cartTable');

      var new_row = table.rows[1].cloneNode(true); // clones the first row 
      var len = table.rows.length; // number of rows in table
      var inp1 = new_row.cells[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
      inp1.value = document.getElementById("Environment").value;
      var inp2 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
      inp2.value = document.getElementById("form").value;
      var inp3 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
      inp3.value = document.getElementById("Type").value;
      var inp4 = new_row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

      inp4.value = document.getElementById("Model").value;

      var inp5 = new_row.cells[4].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];


      inp5.value = document.getElementById("Cpu").value;

      var inp6 = new_row.cells[5].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

      inp6.value = document.getElementById("Memory").value;

      var inp7 = new_row.cells[6].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
      inp7.value = document.getElementById("Storage").value;

      var inp8 = new_row.cells[7].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
      inp8.value = document.getElementById("Servers").value;
      table.appendChild(new_row);
      //hide again after cloning 
      document.getElementById('show').style.display = 'none';

    }
  }
}


function check(s) {
  document.getElementById('Memory').value = '';
  document.getElementById('Cpu').value = '';
  document.getElementById('platforms').innerHTML = '<option>Select Core</option><option>1</option><option>2</option>';
  document.getElementById('mass').innerHTML = '<option>Select memory</option><option>2</option><option>4</option>';


  var c = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
  //Here You Can Start Loading your states with each country
  if (c != "windows" && c != "linux") {
    document.getElementById('Memory').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('Cpu').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('platforms').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('mass').style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('Memory').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('Cpu').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('platforms').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('mass').style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
  <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <br>
  </header>
  <div align="center">
    <form action="GetEstimation" method="post">
      <p id="message"></p>
      <table id="formTable">
        <tbody>

          <tr>
            <td> <label>Environment </label> </td>
            <td> <label>form </label> </td>
            <td> <label>Type </label> </td>

            <td><label id="myLabel">Model</label> </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <select name="Environment" id="Environment" required>
                <option value="" selected Disabled>Select Environment</option>
                <option>abc</option>
                <option>bcd</option>
                <option>efg</option>
              </select>
            </td>

            <td>
              <select name="form" id="form" onchange="check(this)" required>
                <option value="" selected Disabled>Select Platform</option>
                <option>windows</option>
                <option>linux</option>
                <option>solaries</option>

              </select>
            </td>
            <td>
              <select name="Type" id="Type" required>
                <option value="" selected Disabled>Select Server Type</option>
                <option>ABC</option>
                <option>DEF</option>
                <option>QAZ</option>
                <option>ASF</option>
                <option>NS</option>
              </select>
            </td>




            <td>
              <select name="Model" id="Model" required>
                <option value="" selected Disabled>Select Hardware</option>
                <option>abc</option>
                <option>bcd</option>
                <option>efg</option>
              </select>
            </td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> <label>Cpu</label> </td>
            <td> <label>Memory</label> </td>
            <td> <label>Storage</label> </td>
            <td> <label>Servers</label> </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> <input type="text" name="Cpu" id="Cpu" required>
              <select id="mass" style="display:none;"></select>
            </td>
            <td> <input type="text" name="Memory" id="Memory" required>
              <select id="platforms" style="display:none;"></select>
            </td>
            <td> <input type="text" name="Storage" id="Storage" required> </td>
            <td> <input type="text" name="Servers" id="Servers" required> </td>
            <td> <input type="button" class="cartBtn" onclick="addTo()" value="Add to Cart" />

          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>


      <table id="cartTable">

        <tr>
          <th><label>Environment</label></th>
          <th><label>form</label></th>
          <th><label>Type</label></th>
          <th><label>Model</label></th>
          <th><label>Cpu</label></th>
          <th><label>Memory</label></th>
          <th><label>Storage</label></th>
          <th><label>Servers</label></th>
        </tr>

        <tr id="show" style="display:none;">
          <td> <input type="text" readonly></td>
          <td> <input type="text" readonly></td>
          <td> <input type="text" readonly></td>
          <td> <input type="text" readonly></td>
          <td> <input type="text" readonly></td>
          <td> <input type="text" readonly></td>
          <td> <input type="text" readonly></td>
          <td> <input type="text" readonly></td>

          <td><input type="button" class="cartBtn" value="Remove" onclick="remove(this)" /></td>
        </tr>

      </table>

    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: but in this the value of that drop down is not getting inserted in cart table it is just giving blank space

Comment: Updated my answer now check and see.

Comment: Also, i have made one more update.. previous code was not checking `null` value this will check.You can minimize this code according to your requirement.